# Why do variables for HTML template have to be defined outside its own function?

Tags: google-apps-script, html-email, template-engine

I am just curious as to why/how this works.

I have a function called sendEmail that defines a bunch of variables from a spreadsheet then sends the user an email using said variables. However, I get the error that these variables are not defined unless I declare these variables OUTSIDE the function. Anyone know why this is? I just want to better understand how JavaScript works.

Example, the below doesn't work if there is a scriptlet for firstName in the HTML template, it only works when firstName is defined outside the function.

```
function sendEmail () {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Employee Names');
const firstName = ss.getRange(7, 1).getValue();

var htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("EmailTemplate2").evaluate().getContent();

MailApp.sendEmail(
  {to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
  subject: `Attendance Infractions Narrative`,
  htmlBody: htmlBody});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Employee Names');
  let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("EmailTemplate2")
  t.firstName = ss.getRange(7, 1).getValue(); //this will wori with <?= firstName ?>
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    {
      to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
      subject: `Attendance Infractions Narrative`,
      htmlBody: t.evaluate().getContent();
    });
}
```

[example in documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates)